# Unable to start Message Engine in Websphere

Tags: websphere-7

I am facing a problem while starting the websphere message engine for one of the application deployed on websphere. This application is getting deployed automatically as a part of the installation of Websphere Lombardi 7.2 express edition. It's using websphere 7 internally to deploy it. When I try to start the message engine from the administrative console of websphere I am getting following error:

```
The messaging engine ProcessCenter01.twperfsvr-twperfsvr_bus cannot be started as there is no runtime initialized for it yet, retry the operation once it has initialized. For the runtime to successfully initialize the hosting server must be started, have its 'SIB service' already enabled, and dynamic configuration reload enabled. If this is a newly configured messaging engine and it is the first messaging engine to be hosted on this server, then it is most likely the 'SIB service' was not previously enabled and thus the server will need to be restarted. The messaging engine runtime might not be initializing because of an error while trying to start, examine the SystemOut.log of the hosting server to check for error messages indicating the problem.
```

After restarting the server, the same error shows. Can anyone help me to to find what gets loaded as a part of "initialization of runtime"? Are there any config files etc. that I need to check to solve this issue? I am suspecting some missing configuration causing error to load the runtime for this particular application.

Answer (score 3):

I too faced this issue today had to delete all the files under the message store 
check the `directory-file` path mentioned in

**Application servers > server1 > Messaging engines > `XXX.server1-primaryBus` > File store**

Answer (score 1):

Just Enable the SIB Services For the particular Server.

Example:Server-->Application Server-->click on Server Name-->right hand side we can see SIB services-->Check box the Enable services.

This will solve your problem

Comment: One possible source of confusion here is that this check box may already be enabled. In this case, leave it enabled and apply changes and sync across nodes if necessary. This started SIB for me.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have faced the same issue when I rebuilt the jvms in UAT envt. After searching on web I found that because of the old messages saved in the message store(flat files in my envt) the messaging engines was not getting initiated. After deleting the old messaging store and restarting the servers it got initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with this problem too.

In our situation the problem was that the file message store location was used that was already created for a different (or old) message-engine.

If you add a busmember to the service-bus and use a file store implementation, then you need to supply the path for the store and log folder. Make sure these locations don't exist yet, other wise you will run in the problem above. The message-engine for this member will use these folders.

If you have a script for creating the message-bus infrastructure, make sure that when you delete the bus or remove message-engines, that you remove the file store/log folders for these, before you re-run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you are using a external database as a data store, and the user that is used for the connection is not allowed to create a database. You might find a ffdc entry like this:

> DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN;CREATE
>   SCHEMA, DRIVER=3.61.65

Then you have to go to your database administration tool and give DB2ADMIN the proper privileges. Then restart the server or cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this issue is been resolved. I did not create the schema in SQL Server with same name as that of the username I gave to connect SQL Server during the installation of WLE 7.2

Please find details about this at below link: 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/message.jspa?messageID=14795282